# checking if cx_Oracle cur.executemany() is success or not

Tags: python-2.7, cx-oracle

How to check if cur.executemany() is success or not in python?

```
a = self.cur.executemany("""insert into test_table(REQUEST_ID,PLATFORM_NAME,SYSTEM_NAME,DB_NAME,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_DESC,DATA_TYPE,LENGTH,PRECISION,PRIMARY_KEY_FLAG,CREATED_BY_DS_ID) values(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12)""",rowTup)
```

I have tried this but the value in 'a' is 'None' even though the data is inserted to table.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no exception, the call to cursor.executemany() was a success and all of the data should be inserted into the table.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution,

we can add 'batcherrors = True' along with the execute many to check for any errors

```
self.cur.executemany("""insert into test_table(REQUEST_ID,PLATFORM_NAME,SYSTEM_NAME,DB_NAME,TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,COLUMN_DESC,DATA_TYPE,LENGTH,PRECISION,PRIMARY_KEY_FLAG,CREATED_BY_DS_ID) values(:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12)""",rowTup,batcherrors = True, arraydmlrowcounts = True)
                if len(self.cur.getbatcherrors()) == 0:
                    self.updateStatus(...)
                else:
                    self.updateStatus(...)
```

Comment: There are some classes of error that batcherrors won't protect against, starting with syntax errors in your SQL statements so go with Anthony's suggestion.